# How do I make a button not run its command in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

When I try to add a command to a button it runs the command without me pressing the button.
How do I fix this?
For example, if I did this:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()

def a():
   print("Hello")

button = tkinter.Button(root,command=a())
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

and ran it, it would execute the function a() without me pressing the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tkinter.Button(root,command=a())
```

You should **pass** the function, not **call** it, so remove the `()`:

```
tkinter.Button(root,command=a)
```

Comment: thanks I heard that you can also use a lamda like this:
`tkinter.Button(root, command= lambda: a())`

Comment: @LiamHall You can, but why would you? You already have a function (`a`). There is no need to wrap it in another